# jointjs: get position of label and set position to center of link-segments

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I would like to add a label to a link, which I do like this:

```
paper.on({
    'cell:pointerdblclick': function(cellView, event, x, y){            
        // Set label for this link
        if (cellView.model.isLink()) {
            var cellId  = cellView.model.id,
                label   = cellView.model.get('labels'),
                content = 'Text';

            if (label) { // edit existing label
                $('#canvas').prepend('<input type="text" id="overlay" data-id="' + cellId + '" style="top: 20px; left: 20px;" value="' + content + '">');
                $('#overlay').focus().select();
            }
            else { // create new label
                cellView.model.label(0, {
                    position: .5,
                    attrs: {
                        rect: { fill: 'white' },
                        text: { text: 'my label' }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

1. If there is an existing label an overlay is beeing added for editing the text. To get this input field exactly over the label, I need to know the position of this. But the position isn't defined as a absolute position on the paper, but a value relative to the start point. Otherwise I could just use the x and y value for positioning of the input field.
2. I'm using links in manhattan style, that means there could be multiple segments as a link isn't a straight line. Now I would like to position a label always in the center of a segment. Also the label can be dropped from one segment to another segment. But the label attribute `position` uses the complete lenth of the link and not just of one segment. I don't know from where I can get this informations.